# How could we get presentation of FOSS4Geurope 2017?

Tags: references, open-source-gis

I was to the FOSS4Geu 2017 and I could not see all the presentation I would to see. So, as the great team try to get all of them, I thought it's possible to get it throught the [website](https://europe.foss4g.org/2017/).

Unfortunatly I can't figure out where it's possible to download them.

Do you know where presentations are available ? maybe  on a specific FOSS4G page dedicate to that (which I never earded talking about before)!

Comment: @PolyGeo why do you remove presentation tag ?

Comment: Questions like this one are quite localized in time, like all presentations, and I think they are not good candidates for Main.  Also, "[When seeking information about specific (not lists of) books, papers, **presentations**, tutorials, videos of lectures, and other materials](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/references/info)" the [tag:references] tag (which I forgot to replace it with) should be used.

Comment: ok thanks to that. I didn't understood the tag as it should. Note that Presentation tag is not used at all and might be remove from the tag list do be less confused, isn't it ?

Comment: The presentations tag should disappear within 24 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [conference website](https://europe.foss4g.org/2017/Conference) provides a link to a repository with the presentations.

Unfortunately it's hidden behind a link saying "*OSGeo Repo for FOSS4G Europe 2017 Conference*" which is easy to miss.

> https://git.osgeo.org/gogs/foss4g-europe/foss4g-europe-2017-paris

Comment: that exactly what I am looking for ! and the full repository for all OSGEO 's project ! thank a lot

Comment: can we know why there are downvotes, I am curious .